# How to add a related account

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I want to add a related Stack Exchange account to my actual Stack Overflow account. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to a site on the Stack Exchange network, simply make sure that they have the same OpenID (you log in with the same service) and email (required for Google Account users), then log in to any Stack Exchange site. The associations will happen automatically.

If you have problems, please link us to the accounts which you wish to associate.